# Firebase Too Many Requests Exception

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

While working on android app with firebase I sent too much otp requests while testing my app phone authentication and they blocked otp services for my app how can I access otp services again?
[Here is the screenshot of Firebase exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaHJK.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message already says: "Try again later". This type of condition/block is typically cleared after some time, with the exact interval depending on how overly frequent your requests were. Consider [testing with fictional phone numbers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers) to prevent such problems.

If the error persists after a few hours, it might be good to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes it was temporary.